# DispatchQueue - QOS Confusion

Tags: ios, swift

Please consider the following statement:

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .milliseconds(500), qos: .utility, flags: .noQoS) {
    print("What is my QOS?")
}
```

Notice how many of the parameters refer to the quality of service. How can a mere mortal possibility sort out the permutations?

Comment: Looks like DispatchQueue.global has been deprecated...

Comment: @Duncan There are two; one deprecated, the other not. https://developer.apple.com/reference/dispatch/dispatchqueue

Comment: I just figured that out. Derp...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally you shouldn't try to sort out all those permutations. In most cases, messing around too much with QoS is a recipe for trouble. But there are fairly simple rules.

Queues have priorities, and they can assign that priority to blocks that request to inherit.

This particular block is explicitly requesting a lower priority, but then says "ignore my QoS request." As a rule, don't do that. The only reason I know of for doing that is if you're interacting with some legacy API that doesn't understand QoS. (I've never encountered this myself, and it's hard to imagine it coming up in user-level code.)

A more interesting question IMO (and one that comes up much more often in real code) is this one:

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .utility).async(qos: .userInitiated) {}
```

What is the priority of this block? The answer is `.userInitiated`, and the block will "loan" its priority to the queue until it finishes executing. So for some period of time, this entire queue will become `.userInitiated`. This is to prevent priority inversion (where a high-priority task blocks waiting for a low-priority task).

This is all discussed in depth in [Concurrent Programming With GCD in Swift 3](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/720/), which is a must-watch for anyone interested in non-trivial GCD.

Comment: Thanks, Rob. I'll try the video again; it kinda wore me out the first time :-)

Comment: At first I did not really understand Rob's answer. Now that (I think) I do, I'm going to chime back in. Perhaps it will help another like me.

A DispatchQueue's QoS determines how frequently that queue is serviced; how rapidly items are pulled from the queue, assigned to a thread, and thus become candidates for execution. (What the priority of those threads might be is a matter for further exploration).

<continued in the next comment>

Comment: Imagine that the global .utility queue has 50 .utility items on it at the time that a .userInitiated item is submitted. Temporarily elevating the queue's QOS to .userInitiated will cause it to be serviced more frequently, resulting in the 50 "ahead of me" items being pulled off more rapidly, resulting in the .userInitiated item being pulled from the queue sooner than it otherwise would have been. This is my current understanding. Let the learning continue.

Comment: This isn't necessarily quite right. It's not frequency of servicing. It's just order. If there are any .userInitiated items ready to run anywhere, they're going to run before any lower priorities run. utility is "when you have nothing at all better to do." Queues can starve if higher priority queues keep getting new blocks. But correct about the 50 "ahead of me" items. They will be bumped up to userInitiated in this case. They'll still be in order, but it makes sure the high priority block doesn't get blocked by them.

Comment: I know this is an old question, so forgive me, but does it really elevate everything on the global queue? I would have expected this only on custom queues and I don't see examples in that video that explicitly use global queues. I haven't found disclaimers either way.